# Understanding xsd:choice and minOccurs

Tags: xml, xsd

I am having trouble understanding the behavior of the following XML schema:

```
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xsd:element name="rootnode">
    <xsd:complexType>
      <xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:choice minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="2">
          <xsd:element name="e1" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="2"/>
          <xsd:element name="e2" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
        </xsd:choice>
      </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:complexType>
  </xsd:element>
</xsd:schema>
```

I expected at least one instance of either element `<e1>` or `<e2>` be required as a child of `<rootnode>`. Despite my expectations, an empty `<rootnode>` will validate against this schema:

```
 > xmllint --schema test.xsd empty.xml
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <rootnode>
 </rootnode>
 empty.xml validates
```

If I change the `minOccurs` attribute of element `e2` to something other than `"0"`, I get the behavior I originally expected.

- It seems as though the mere *absence* of element `<e2>` counts as an occurrence of the `xsd:choice` in my example.
- If this is the case, then how come this infinite number of occurrences does not violate the `maxOccurs` limit in my `xsd:choice`?

Answer (score 105, accepted):

I tell you you can go to the shops at least once and at most twice, and each time you have a choice of what to buy: you can buy apples (either one apple or two apples), or you can buy oranges (either no oranges or one orange).

It's entirely possible that you will choose to go to the shops twice and on each occasion to buy no oranges. So you come back with nothing.

Comment: @mizo writes (in an answer I deleted): I drew a decision tree of this, and concluded that the choice can result in eleven distinct sequences. If I decide to "go shopping" once, I can end up with e1, e1 e1, nothing or e2. If I decide to "go shopping" twice, I can end up with any of the previous four permutations or e1 e1 e1, e1 e2, e1 e1 e1 e1, e1 e1 e2, e2 e1, e2 e1 e1 or e2 e2. Is this correct? – mizo 6 hours ago

Comment: This is why I eat bananas: there's fewer branches in banana trees.

Answer (score 2):

Here are the allowable combinations

```
Two choices:
e1 (1 - 2) + e1 (1 - 2) = e1 x (2 - 4), or
e1 (1 - 2) + e2 (0 - 1), or 
e2 (0 - 1) + e1 (1 - 2), or
e2 (0 - 1) + e2 (0 - 1) = e2 (0 - 2)

One choice (but no new outcomes):
e1 (1-2), or
e2 (0-1)


e1e1, e1e1e1, e1e1e1e1
e1, e1e2, e1e1e2 
e2e1, e2e1e1 
empty, e2, e2e2
```

Note that choice[min=2 max=2] would have produced the same set of valid combinations.

Comment: Alright, so that counts as eleven if you remove the duplicate `e1e1`. Sure enough, the `minOccurs` on `choice` seems to have no effect, if one of the children elements has `minOccurs="0"`.

Comment: Right, 11 unique possibilities.  Note that minOccurs="1" is the default, so removing the attribute doesn't change the minOccurs value.  Even when you set the minOccurs=2, the set of valid combos shouldn't change.  As long as one of the valid choices has minOccurs=0, I conclude that the choice attributes where minOccurs = maxOccurs produces the same set as where the minOccurs < maxOccurs.