# Understanding xsd:choice with minOccurs attribute

Tags: xml, xsd

I'm trying to understand how xsd:choice and minOccurs work together.
I read [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5214555/understanding-xsdchoice-and-minoccurs), but it just responded to half of my question.
For example, I've this type :

```
<xsd:element name="CAR">
  <xsd:complexType>
    <xsd:sequence>
       <xsd:choice>
        <xsd:element name="A"/>
        <xsd:element name="B"/>
       </xsd:choice>
    </xsd:sequence>
  </xsd:complexType>
</xsd:element>
```

If I want to make it possible to not specify any of `CAR`'s elements (neither A nor B), I can add minOccurs like this:

```
<xsd:element name="CAR">
  <xsd:complexType>
    <xsd:sequence>
       <xsd:choice>
        <xsd:element name="A" minOccurs="0"/>
        <xsd:element name="B" minOccurs="0"/>
       </xsd:choice>
    </xsd:sequence>
  </xsd:complexType>
</xsd:element>
```

But is it true that if I put it on only one element, either A or B, it will result on the same? In other words, is it true that my previous example =

```
<xsd:element name="CAR">
  <xsd:complexType>
    <xsd:sequence>
       <xsd:choice>
        <xsd:element name="A" minOccurs="0"/>
        <xsd:element name="B"/>
       </xsd:choice>
    </xsd:sequence>
  </xsd:complexType>
</xsd:element>
```

=

```
<xsd:element name="CAR">
  <xsd:complexType>
    <xsd:sequence>
       <xsd:choice>
        <xsd:element name="A"/>
        <xsd:element name="B" minOccurs="0"/>
       </xsd:choice>
    </xsd:sequence>
  </xsd:complexType>
</xsd:element>
```

In these three examples, I'll be able to specify any element (neither A nor B), right?

Comment: FYI: By convention the namespace prefix for XML Schema is `xs`, not `xsd`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd express it a little differently:

```
<xsd:element name="CAR">
  <xsd:complexType>
    <xsd:choice minOccurs="0">
      <xsd:element name="A" />
      <xsd:element name="B" />
    </xsd:choice>
  </xsd:complexType>
</xsd:element>
```

But to answer your question, a choice between `<A>` or `<B>` where both are optional (`minOccurs="0"`) is logically equivalent to a choice between `<A>` or `<B>` where either one is optional.

In other words, *one* of the conditions of the `<xsd:choice>` must be fulfilled. By declaring `minOccurs="0"` on one of the options, you effectively allow that to match when no child is found (i.e. *"There is no `<B>`, so what we have here must be an `<A>` which is missing, which is OK."*)

Comment: Ok, thank you. Can you give me some explanation about `<xs:choice minOccurs="0">` please?

Comment: Well, I thought that would be self-evident...? *If* there is a child then it has to be one of the choice options. However there doesn't *have to be* a child, that's what `minOccurs="0"` says. (As you've noticed yourself, there are quite a few ways to express the same thing, I just think this is the most logical one.)