# Can XSD choice be empty?

Tags: xml, xsd

I've read the XSD specification but I'm still confused. Is an empty choice valid in XSD? I mean, with a simple choice with no attributes declared, is mandatory to have either element "a" or element "b", or can it be empty?

```
<xs:complexType name="ChoiceType">
    <xs:choice>
        <xs:element name="a" type="type_a"/>
        <xs:element name="b" type="type_b"/>
    </xs:choice>
</xs:complexType>
```

Comment: You have three answers, together answering two or three different questions.  Which were you asking? Do you mean 'Can the xsd:choice element be empty?', or 'Can a choice in the content model match an empty sequence in the document instance?', or something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could be empty in this scenario

```
<xs:complexType name="ChoiceType">
    <xs:choice minOccurs="0">
        <xs:element name="a" type="type_a"/>
        <xs:element name="b" type="type_b"/>
    </xs:choice>
</xs:complexType>
```

anyway see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5214555/understanding-xsdchoice-and-minoccurs)

Comment: I understand then that the default value for minOccurs is 1.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the element governed by an `xsd:choice` can be empty, *if `minOccurs="0"` is used*:

- `minOccurs="0"` can be on the `xsd:choice` itself.
- `minOccurs="0"` can be on all of the children.

Related answer: An `xsd:choice` itself can be empty and would indicate that the element being defined must be empty.

Finally, note that in your example, no, one of `a` or `b` must be present because the default for `minOccurs` is `1`.

Answer (score 1):

Actually it's quite legal to say

```
<xs:choice minOccurs="17"/>
```

but there is no instance document that will be valid against this content model. The instance must conform to one of the alternatives, and if there are no alternatives, then this isn't going to be possible.

It can actually be useful to define types that no instance will satisfy, e.g. if you want to restrict a type down to nothing.