# XSD validation using choice

Tags: xml, xsd

I have below XSD and XML.

**XSD:**

```
    <xs:choice  minOccurs="3" maxOccurs="100" >
    <xs:element name="noticeOfEligibilityHCC"  minOccurs="0" />
    <xs:element name="noticeOfEligibilitySNAP"  minOccurs="0" />
    <xs:element name="noticeOfEligibilityTANF"  minOccurs="0" />
    <xs:element name="displayNoticeAttachment" type="xs:string" minOccurs="1" />
    <xs:element name="additionalComments" type="xs:string" minOccurs="1" />
    <xs:element name="noticeOfEligibilityCCAP"  minOccurs="0" />
    <xs:element name="noticeOfEligibilityLIHEAP"  minOccurs="0" />
    <xs:element name="noticeOfEligibilityLIHEAPShare"  minOccurs="0" />
    <xs:element name="noticeOfEligibilityEmergencyLIHEAP"  minOccurs="0" />
    </xs:choice>
```

**XML:**

```
<displayNoticeAttachment>N</displayNoticeAttachment>
<additionalComments></additionalComments>
```

Here in above XSD `displayNoticeAttachment` and `additionalComments` elements are mandatory.

I want to validate the XML against mentioned XSD.
The validation should be successful, if any of the element is present along with mandatory elements, else it should throw validation error.

As per my XSD its giving validation successful in every cases.
Can you please correct, where I am wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Here you can find excellent explanation why your xsd always produces successful validations: [Understanding xsd:choice and minOccurs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5214555/understanding-xsdchoice-and-minoccurs)

One of the possible solutions for you would be:

```
<xs:sequence>
    <xs:element name="displayNoticeAttachment" type="xs:string" minOccurs="1" />
    <xs:element name="additionalComments" type="xs:string" minOccurs="1" />
    <xs:choice  minOccurs="3" maxOccurs="100" >
        <xs:element name="noticeOfEligibilityHCC"  minOccurs="0" />
        <xs:element name="noticeOfEligibilitySNAP"  minOccurs="0" />
        <xs:element name="noticeOfEligibilityTANF"  minOccurs="0" />
        <xs:element name="noticeOfEligibilityCCAP"  minOccurs="0" />
        <xs:element name="noticeOfEligibilityLIHEAP"  minOccurs="0" />
        <xs:element name="noticeOfEligibilityLIHEAPShare"  minOccurs="0" />
        <xs:element name="noticeOfEligibilityEmergencyLIHEAP"  minOccurs="0" />
    </xs:choice>
</xs:sequence>
```

This is just an example taking into accout there were no special requirements for element ordering, etc (note that `minOccurs=3` would pass the empty set since in your example you're choosing among the elements having items with  `minOccurs=0`). You are free to elaborate the schema that is a best fit for your particular case.